# url helpers in assets that respect an application sub uri

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got a js.erb file in a rails 3.2 application that uses a url helper to fill in the url field on a jquery $.ajax call. It works fine when I use the path_to_method_url/path on my local machine correctly pointing to localhost:3000/path_to_method. When I put it in our staging environment that has a sub uri it points to example-staging.com/path_to_method instead of example-staging.com/sub-uri/path_to_method. Anyone know how to get the url helpers in assets to respect the sub-uri?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try override the `default_url_options` in your application_controller.rb

```
def default_url_options(options = {})
  {:suburi => get_sub_uri}
end
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-url_options

http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html#M000467

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it by changing the url helper in my `js.erb` file from `<action>_path` to  `<action>_url` then adding the default host (including the sub uri) to each environment config like this:

#### config/environments/development.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = 'localhost:3000'
```

#### config/environments/staging.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = 'example-staging.com/sub-uri'
```